# Save DataStore Query Result as list in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Below is how i read data from my data store

```
AllScores = User_Scores.all()
for score in AllScores:
      # i make query for my data
```

But in a case when i want to read data from my datastore for many time, i tried something like this

```
UserName= ['name1','name2','name3']
AllScores = User_Scores.all():
count = 0
while (count < len(UserName))
    tempScore = AllScores
    tempScore.filter("name = ",Username[count])
    for score in AllScores:
        # i make query for my data
    count++
```

but the problem is that after the first filter, it affect the rest consecutive result, an i get data's that is inaccurate. How do i save

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What do you mean by inaccurate results? Also, what are you trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine Datastore can only guarantee eventually consistent results: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency (first paragraph).

So, you need save entity with "parent" and read using ancestor query - as explained in example on page as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing some concepts.

As specified in the [appengine db documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter):

- The second argument of `filter(property_operator, value)` should be a value.
- `filter` modifies the query object.

If you're trying to get *all* names, you shouldn't filter on the name property.